# css transitions with print styles

Tags: css

```
/* Content */
#content {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0 !important;
  border-top-left-radius: 0 !important;
  margin-top:0;
  float:left;
  display:block !important;
  width:100%;
  margin-left:0 !important;
  padding-top:70px;
  padding-left:205px;
  transition: padding 0.25s ease;
  -moz-transition: padding 0.25s ease;
  -webkit-transition: padding 0.25s ease;
}

@media print {

   #content {
     margin: 0 !important;
     padding: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

If I remove the transition the stylesheet works as expected, otherwise when printing I have about 70px gap at the top.

It appears that the padding property is not applied in the @print style because of the transition. If I remove the css transition, the print styles get applied. Why is this happening so?

Comment: After 400+ questions and 40+ answers, I'd expect you to know how to ask a question. What are you asking exactly?

Comment: @SecondRiduko The post describes an unexpected problem. The implication that a solution to the problem is desired is pretty obvious. Maybe edit the post to append "How do I solve this problem?"?

Comment: I added more details that appears that the padding style is not applied when printing

Comment: I am trying to explain as best I can. What I am trying to explain is when doing css transitions, it causes the print styles to NOT get applied. If I remove the transition the print styles get applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing this for print styles:

```
transition: none;
-moz-transition: none;
-webkit-transition: none;
```

Answer (score 1):

Bizarre! In absence of any insight, how about setting the transition properties in a separate rule wrapped in a `@media screen` query?