# Cannot override padding in print style when transition-duration is set

Tags: html, css

I have a peculiar problem that only seems to affect Chrome (tested in Chromium 47.0.2526.73 on Ubuntu, Chrome 48.0.2564.82 m on Windows, Firefox 43.0.4 on Ubuntu), and only in an *actual* print-preview (the problem does not occur when emulating print media in the developer tools).

I have been trying to fix an issue with the print styles in GitLab, in which there is an undesirable gap on the left-hand side of the page, as shown below.

[image: excess margin in print preview on GitLab page]

Now, one would expect this to be an easy fix. The main container element has a padding-left of 230px to leave room for the sidebar, which needs to be zero when printing. However, I cannot get a print style in place that actually eliminates this padding.

I have reduced it down to a minimal test case, as shown [here](http://dewar.co.nz/print_test.html). I'd use an in-place snippet, but that doesn't work so well when you try to print-preview it. The source of my example is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Print style problem demonstration</title>
<style type="text/css" media="all">
.page-with-sidebar {
  background: purple!important;
  transition-duration: .3s;
}

@media(min-width: 1199px) {
  .page-sidebar-expanded {
    padding-left: 230px;
  }
}
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
.page-with-sidebar, .page-sidebar-expanded { 
  padding-left: 0!important;
  transition-duration: 0s!important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>I have no left padding.</p>

<div class="page-sidebar-expanded page-with-sidebar">
  <p style="color: white;">I should have no left padding when printed</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In this example, I am trying to eliminate the padding of the purple p when printing by setting `padding-left: 0!important;` in the print style. I have isolated the problem to the `transition-duration: .3s;` style, and the problem goes away if it is removed. However, setting `transition-duration: 0s!important;` does not successfully override it.

[image: purple element with unwanted padding in print preview]

I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748124/css-transitions-with-print-styles), which is the most relevant I could find, but the solutions described do not appear to work for me (making the transition screen-only, and adding the other `transition: none` lines).

One further observation of interest is the the problem also relies on the `@media(min-width: 1199px)` rule. If this is removed, the problem also goes away.

None of the factors I've identified that make this problem occur are easily changeable by me in GitLab, and even if they were I'd really love to know what is causing this behaviour.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in Chrome?

Comment: did you tried with -webkit- prefix?

Comment: Yes - at least I tried `-webkit-transition: none;` as suggested in the thread I linked to. I haven't tried `-webkit-transition-duration: 0s` though, I'll give that a go tomorrow.

Comment: Interesting... The problem does *not* occur on Chromium 45.0.2454.101 on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 on a different PC.

Comment: try <style type="text/css" media="screen"> to give padding and transition in media="screen" instead of using all

Comment: Thanks Umer, even then, the problem still occurs - which is completely bizarre. Not only should the padding not be applied in the first place, but it still can't be overridden!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I logged this as a potential bug in Chromium, and it's now been [verified as such](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=579825), which I think answers this question.

> Able to reproduce on Windows 7, Mac OS 10.11.2 and Ubuntu 14.04 using chrome stable M48 - 48.0.2564.82.
>
> ## Bisect Information:
>
> Good Build: 47.0.2524.0
>   Bad Build : 47.0.2526.0

As a workaround (until the fix is released) I will try leaving the padding in place, and using negative margin to counteract it.

Answer (score 0):

the main issue is transition property, you can write it inside media check the following css, i have tested this as well and working fine.

```
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
        .page-with-sidebar {
            background: purple!important;
        }

    @media(min-width: 1199px) {
        .page-with-sidebar {
            transition-duration: .3s;
        }
        .page-sidebar-expanded {
            padding-left: 230px;
        }
    }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
        .page-with-sidebar, .page-sidebar-expanded { 
            padding-left: 0!important;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Thanks Umer, this does work for me but it's not a valid change, as the margin needs to apply for all screen-widths. If I add another media rule with max-width: 1198px and put it in there as well, the problem returns.

Comment: you can use than, `@media(min-device-width: 0px) {
            .page-with-sidebar {
                transition-duration: .3s;
            }
}` the transition applies on all screens and it may not effect on print

Comment: Thanks Umer, unfortunately that doesn't solve it for me. Are you sure the version of Chrome you are using actually suffers from the problem?

Comment: yes i have tested it's working fine in my chrome version 47.0.2526.111